# How to I scroll the page programmatically in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, gridsome

Bit of a noob question:

I am trying to jump to the bottom of the page when the page has fully loaded. How do I do this?

This is the plain js code that I fail to implement in Vue:

```js
let bottomLoad () => {
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
}

window.eventListener("load", bottomLoad)
```

Comment: Try using Vue methods instead: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted

Comment: There's a vue library that might make it easier for you. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-scrollto

Answer (score -1):

In vue , mounted function is called when page or component have fully loaded . So you can try in that function like below ...

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 mounted: function() {
    window.scrollTo({ top:document.body.scrollHeight, behavior: 'smooth'});
 }
})
```

```css
#scrooll {
  height: 1900px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#scrooll h1 {
position:absolute;
top: 1800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div id="scrooll">
  <h1>Hey I shoud be at bottom</h1>
</div>
</div>
```